# Get value from firebase database based on .getUid()

Tags: android, json, database, firebase

I'm working with Android Studio and Firebase and was wondering how I could do the following as there doesn't seem to be much online on how to do this. So I have a table 'users' which contains information about a user and the ID for that table is the users id generated in FirebaseAuth which can be retrieved using .getUid(). I want to query the users table to retrieve some of that data based on the current users id. I would put up some of my code but this is for an assignment. Any pointers would be greatly appreicated. Thanks

[image]

So I'm wanting to retrieve a value through this table based on EINOwbk5p... so that I'm retrieveing data for the current authorised user.

Comment: Can you please provide us your database structure?

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDbReferenceUserChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser= mFirebaseDatabaseReferenceUserChild.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // TO GET USERDETAILS FOR CURRENT USER
            String userDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This way you can fetch data of CURRENT USER from "users" table by passing CURRENT USER's uId.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing code or your data structure, but are you looking at retrieving a db item from the key? If so this might help:

```
private DatabaseReference myRef;
myRef = ....
User getUser = myRef.child(userKey);

getUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {....}
```